# Multiple Alarm is not setting

Tags: android

I'm store date and time  in parse and get there all the data but even a single alarm is not triggered . For Example i store the time in data base like 2pm, 3pm,4pm etc along with their dates but no Alarm is triggered . 
Please Help me ..

This is my Main Class

```
   ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray; 

  AlarmManager alarmManager =(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

 intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();



 Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Description");

   query.whereEqualTo("user", user);

   query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

 @Override

 public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e)                     
if (e == null) {
int count = 0;
     for (ParseObject obj : list) {

    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, obj.getInt("Year"));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, obj.getInt("Month"));
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, obj.getInt("Day"));
   calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, obj.getInt("Hour"));
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, obj.getInt("Miniute"));
  calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

   Intent intent = new Intent("net.learn2develop.DisplayNotification");

     intent.putExtra("NotifID", 1);

  PendingIntent  
 pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),ncount++,intent,    
 0);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis()
,pendingIntent);

    intentArray.add(pendingIntent);

}//end for loop

  } else {

      Log.d("Test", "Error Occur");

 }  

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set multiple alarms (repeating or single), then you just need to create their PendingIntents with different requestCode. If requestCode is the same, then the new alarm will overwrite the old one.

Here is the code to create multiple single alarms and keep them in ArrayList.

```
// context variable contains your `Context`
AlarmManager mgrAlarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
   // Loop counter `i` is used as a `requestCode`
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, 0);
   // Single alarms in 1, 2, ..., 10 minutes (in `i` minutes)
   mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000 * i, 
                pendingIntent); 

   intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
}
```

You can also see the Question:[How to set more than one alarms at a time in android?](http:////%20context%20variable%20contains%20your%20%60Context%60%20AlarmManager%20mgrAlarm%20=%20(AlarmManager)%20context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);%20ArrayList%3CPendingIntent%3E%20intentArray%20=%20new%20ArrayList%3CPendingIntent%3E();%20%20for(i%20=%200;%20i%20%3C%2010;%20++i)%20%7B%20%20%20%20Intent%20intent%20=%20new%20Intent(context,%20OnAlarmReceiver.class);%20%20%20%20//%20Loop%20counter%20%60i%60%20is%20used%20as%20a%20%60requestCode%60%20%20%20%20PendingIntent%20pendingIntent%20=%20PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,%20i,%20intent,%200);%20%20%20%20//%20Single%20alarms%20in%201,%202,%20...,%2010%20minutes%20(in%20%60i%60%20minutes)%20%20%20%20mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()%20+%2060000%20*%20i,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pendingIntent);%20%20%20%20%20%20intentArray.add(pendingIntent);%20%7D)

Comment: You need to use PendingIntent.getBroadcast  which will take different Broadcast id's for pending intent.                                               PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, 0);